# Calculating Terrain Roughness Index using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am trying to calculate Terrain Roughness Index (TRI) as written up in [Riley et al 1999](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/reference-docs/Terrain_Ruggedness_Index.pdf), and have used the python code located [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=334346db638844039dc1c4abf5dd8d00). However, this approach converts a raster to a numpy array and then iterates over the rows.

This can be relatively slow, so is there a way to use ArcGIS Pro to write a custom focal statistics script to calculate a TRI value for each cell over a moving window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I would just calculate a focal variance. Variance within a 3x3 window is very close to TRI `[sqrt(sum(dev^2)]`. The variance would also be more scalable than TRI which is limited to a square 3x3 window. You could use the raster calculator to calculate an algebraic approximation of the index.

ArcGIS (type) syntax:

```
s = FocalStatistics(dem, NbrRectangle(3, 3, MAP), "SUM", "")
d = (dem * dem)
t = FocalStatistics(d, NbrRectangle(3, 3, MAP), "SUM", "")
tri = sqrt( t + 9 * d - 2 * dem * s )
```

There are several geomorphometric indices available in the [ArcGIS Geomorphometry & Gradient Metrics toolbox](https://github.com/jeffreyevans/GradientMetrics) that would provide alternatives to TRI. There is an actual implementation of TRI, that provides optional corrections and standardization of the index, in the R [spatialEco package](https://github.com/jeffreyevans/spatialEco) available on CRAN or GitHub.